# How can I set different background color for each row in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I want to set different background color in each row of listview ? I used custom adapter for [listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). It should be appear when activity loads.static different color row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said that you have use Custom adapter for listview then what you need to do is below.
in `getView` method of your adapter you need to set background color of your list row xml's parent view.

Comment: im not getting what are you saying.

Comment: i think you need to check @Samir update and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 13):

in `getView(...) method`

```
if (position == 0) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_even);
} else if (position == 1) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_odd);
} else...
```

**Update::**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
    holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdesc);

    holder.title.setText("Title" + position);
    holder.description.setText("Desc" + position);

    //here set your color as per position

    if (position == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_even);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_odd);
    }
    return view;
}
```

**holder class**

```
public class ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public TextView description;
}
```

Comment: here is the good solution...

// Even and odd Row...
        if ((position % 2) == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_even);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_odd);
        }

you have the good solution in your website!

Answer (score 5):

Make an array as given below as no of list item i suppose u have five items

```
 int[] color_arr={Color.BLUE,Color.CYAN,Color.DKGRAY,Color.GREEN,Color.RED};
```

and after do in ur getView method of custome adapter as below

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {

     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     View row=convertView;

     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custome, parent, false);
     row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);// this set background color

     TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
     ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_list);

     textview.setText(data_text[position]);
     imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

     return (row);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valueable suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, If available more then 5 items and colors are 5 only, how it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = convertView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custome, parent, false);
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);// this set background color

    TextView textview = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_list);

    textview.setText(data_text[position]);
    imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);
    if (position == 0) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if (position % 2 == 1) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if (position % 2 == 0) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    return (rowView);

}
```