# Android : Alternate colors in ListView using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, background-color, android-arrayadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i set differnt background color for each row in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479108/how-can-i-set-differnt-background-color-for-each-row-in-listview)

How can i add different/alretnate colors for listview items? The below is my code to add items to ListView using ArrayAdapter

```
list  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.planetList);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListViewActivity.this, R.layout.my_list_row, R.id.planetNameTextView);

for (int i = 0; i < planetNamesArray.length; i++) {
adapter.add(planetNamesArray[i]);
}
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can anyone guide me to add the different background colors using ArrayAdapter as i'am a newbie to android

Comment: you better use custom adapter to achieve this

Answer (score 6):

you firstly need to use custom adapter,in its getView() method u have to check the position.

```
if(position % 2 == 0)
           row.setcolor(R.color.color1);
else 
      row.setcolor(R.color.color2);
```

hope u get the point.

Answer (score 3):

Create custom adapter class by extending `BaseAdapter`.

Once you do this, you will get **getView()** method, inside that method you can do operations for Views you want for your list item.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if(position[i]%2==0)
  {
     // even position color
  }
  else
  {
    // odd position color
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Custome adapter.. a pseudo code would look like this..

```
Class MyAdpater extends BaseAdapter{

public ColorAndData{

private Color color;
private Data data;
}
ColorAndData dataAndColor[];
public MyAdapter(ColorAndData[] data)
this.dataAndColor=data;

}

public view getView(View convertView)
{
dataAndColor.getColor() //and set color
dataAndColor.getdata() //and set data

}
```

Comment: Isn't getView() overrided method?

Comment: @PareshMayani ..  that is why i wrote pseudo code.. its not the exact code but just an idea,..

Comment: oh yes, then its fine :)