# Alternative colors in ArrayList items in Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, background-color

I want alternatively different colors for my ArrayList items which I am generating dynamically. I don't want to do it with setBackgroundColor() method of getView() as I have implemented my entire application with onListItemClick().So is there any other method to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can programetically set bg color of list item it's easy

Comment: How are you displaying the arraylist items???

Comment: You cant alter a view's property without referencing it. which means in order to change different rows to different colors you'll have to either implement your own adapter or implement your own listview view.

Comment: @Goofy-  ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, item);
      getListView().setAdapter(fileList);

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid please refer to my answer it will definitely help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these links it will help you...

[Android : Alternate colors in ListView using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510910/android-alternate-colors-in-listview-using-arrayadapter)

http://emumair.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/creating-an-alternate-colored-list-view-in-android/

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

http://dustinbreese.blogspot.in/2009/12/creating-listview-with-alternating.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom adapter and in getView method get the reference of backgound layout and set your color. make sure it will generate random color because for every row getView() gets called. As  its random color you will get your desired output