# Colouring a ListView in oncreate

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and i would like to set diffrent color to each item based on an 
`ArrayList<Integer>` if the item's position exists in the Array the background of that item will be Green otherwise it should be Red. I used `SetListColor` to do that but it doesn't work.

```
public class createtarget extends ListActivity
{

         String [] Target;
    ListView lstView;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> coloredItems;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.createtarget);

        coloredItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        coloredItems.add(1);

        lstView = getListView();    
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);        
        lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        SetListColor(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)); // Get View of ListView

        Target=new String []{"A","B","C"};

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, Target));

    }


public void SetListColor(View v)
     {
        for(int i=0;i<lstView.getCount();i++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Item is: "+i);
         if(createtarget.coloredItems.contains(i))
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
         else
             v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red); 
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use  [Base Adepter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) rather fixing your view run-time.

And refer that SO question

[Android : Alternate colors in ListView using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510910/android-alternate-colors-in-listview-using-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the list items you need to act on the ListAdapter, not on the List as a whole.

Just Extend your [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and override the method

[public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

to change the color of the view before returning it (use the position to find out what is what)

The code for the method should look more or like like this (this changes the color depending on the position, even or odd, of the cell):

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if(position%2 == 0)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);        
    else
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    return v;
}
```

*Note: this code has not been tested*

Hope this helps

**EDIT**: corrected the call to getView to be applied to super. Kudos to the poster of the question who pointed this out (somehow his edit has been rejected, it shouldn't have been).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the style to apply color on listview items but one general way to write custom adapter and set rowView BackgroundColor like.

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(v!= null)
        {
         for(int i=0;i<lstView.getCount();i++){
           if(createtarget.coloredItems.contains(i))
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
           }else{
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red); 
           }
         }
        }           
   return v;
}
```