# Android:How can I change the color of one item of the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I override SimpleAdapter:

```
class NoticelistAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
 {
    public NoticelistAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Map<String,Object> map= list.get(position);
        int readState =  (Integer) map.get("ReadState");
        if (readState == 1)
        {
            // do something to change the color of title
        }
        return convertView;
    }
 }
```

And the adapter is:

```
adapter = new NoticelistAdapter(NoticelistActivity.this, list, R.layout.row_noticelist,
                                    new String[] { "Title", "RealName","Date"}, 
                                    new int[] { R.id.noticetitle, R.id.noticerealname,R.id.noticedate});
```

There is an int parameter in each map called "readstate", if the readstate == 1, then I want change the color of "Title" (TextView) to another color.
I know I should override getView(...) in my adapter, but I dont know how to do this. Will you please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First see this :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the Adapter's `getItemViewType()` to return two different layout flags, and override `getViewTypeCount()` to return the number of views. Then depending on flag, set the row layout in `getView()`:

```
 private static final int TYPE_READ = 0;
 private static final int TYPE_NON_READ = 1;
 private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_NON_READ + 1;
 //...

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         int readState =  (Integer) mMap.get("ReadState");
        if(readState==1){
           return TYPE_READ;
        }else{
           return TYPE_NON_READ;
        }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_READ:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_one, null);
                    //set read layout
                    break;
                case TYPE_NON_READ:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_two, null);
                    // set non-read layout
                    break;
            }
    //etc
```

Here is a [complete tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Answer (score 2):

In get view method. Check the postions. If poistion==row0 then set background the background color using drawable.. You can custom style each listview row also with row border.    http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/User_Interface/Working_with_ListViews_and_Adapters/Part_3_-_Customizing_a_ListView's_Appearance. The link will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you have use Custom adapter for listview as you created and then what you need to do is below. In getView method of your adapter you need to set background color of your list row xml's parent view. you can also change each row color based on your requirements.

Refer this [How can I set different background color for each row in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479108/how-can-i-set-differnt-background-color-for-each-row-in-listview)

Comment: if (readState == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_even);
        }